# Leaftlet: Adding feature overlay to control, dynamically

Tags: leaflet, polymer, leaflet.draw

I need to add a `FeatureGroup` to the overlays list. I do add some overlays when instantiating the Leaflet map, but I now need to append a `FeatureGroup` dynamically, ie. based on some run time conditions.

Can someone please help with appending the leaflet control layers? I simply cannot figure whether that's even possible at all. I can add the new layer to the map, but not to the overlays control section. I have also managed to add this new layer dynamically to a new control, but I need to append it to the existing control.

As a side note, I am trying to use Polymer on top of Leaflet map.

Comment: You can try setting a higher z-index for the control element in the css (.leaflet-control-zoom), it might help

Comment: The control element is visible, I just want to add an extra overlay to it.

Comment: Sorry, make sense now. Have you checked the documentation about Panes. This might help: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Answer (score -1):

You can add new layers with [control.addOverlay(layer, name)](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-addoverlay).

And removing it from the control with `control.removeLayer(layer)`

Comment: Right, but how can I get a hold of `control`?

Comment: In a variable while creating it. `var control = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map)`

Comment: That creates a new control. I want to append the overlay to an existing `Control`.

Comment: Yes this is clear ... use your existing code and apply the return value to the `control` variable, then you can append new layers with `control.addOverlay`

Comment: The control is initially filled in by a wrapper on top of Leaflet, so unless Leaflet has some built-in support for adding an overlay after the map gets initialized, I guess I need to dig into the library and see what I can do.

Comment: This function is from leaflet self and this is the exact way how an overlay is added to the control after the map is intializied. But I yes I guess too that it would be good if you read through the docs first